Loading pre-trained Transformer model with AddedTokens using from_pretrained
I have pre-trained a "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" model using the transformers library. Since my model uses additional tokens, I added them to the tokeniser before training and fine-tuned the "embed_tokens" module of the network. My training code looked like this:
  tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",trust_remote_code=True, token=hf_token)
  tokenizer.add_special_tokens({ "additional_special_tokens":[AddedToken("<|move|>"),
                                                              AddedToken("<|endmove|>"),
                                                              AddedToken("<|end|>")]})

  model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=device_map,
    token=hf_token
  )
  model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
  peft_config = LoraConfig(
      lora_alpha=lora_alpha,
      lora_dropout=lora_dropout,
      r=lora_r,
      bias="none",
      modules_to_save= ["embed_tokens", "lm_head"],
      task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
  )

The model trained and saved successfully. However, when trying to load it using AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained, I get the following error:
Error(s) in loading state_dict for LlamaForCausalLM:
size mismatch for model.embed_tokens.modules_to_save.default.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([32003, 4096]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([32000, 4096]).
size mismatch for lm_head.modules_to_save.default.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([32003, 4096]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([32000, 4096])

I appreciate the error is due to the fact that the fine-tuned model has three additional tokens and that causes a mismatch, but how should I load a pre-trained model with a different input shape like mine?
I looked into the transformers API docs for a way to load models with AddedTokens, but I couldn't find anything. I read a blog post mentioning that passing ignore_mismatched_sizes=True to the from_pretrained function would solve the issue, but it didn't work for me.
EDIT: To load my local model, I use the same from_pretrained function that I use to load the meta-llama model from huggingface:
`model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    local_model_folder,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=device_map,
    token=hf_token
  )

This works correctly when loading pre-trained models with no changes to the vocabulary size.

are you trying the load the parameters of the model you saved locally? can you share that code segment?

Yes, I am. I am just using the from_pretrained function to load my local model. I edited my original question to include the code I use.

(1) Check if you still have this error when saving and loading not-quantized model.
(2) please post a link to complete error trace (like in github gist)
(3) most likely you'd need to open an issue in transformers. Just post the issue link here

This GitHub solution worked for me:
  tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",trust_remote_code=True, token=hf_token)
  tokenizer.add_special_tokens({ "additional_special_tokens":[AddedToken("<|move|>"),
                                                              AddedToken("<|endmove|>"),
                                                              AddedToken("<|end|>")]})

  model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=device_map,
    token=hf_token
  )
  model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

  model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, local_model_folder)

